# How To use HTML tags Instead of XML for the User Interface In Android

Tags: android, html, xml

I want to Use HTML Tag instead of XML to Design the Layouts(user interface   part).So can i use the HTML tags.Any Help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to Use HTML Tag instead of XML to Design the Layouts

*Not Possible.*

Because all layouts for native development is designed using xml as in other language like in C# we use `XAML` for designing ui screens for application.
You can also create all views dynamically.

if HTML is required for application then you can design html pages and use WebView for loading page*s.(Not good if you are developing native application*)

You can also use Hybrid frameworks like  *Phonegap , titanium , Windev* to develop  application using HTML,CSS and javascript

Comment: Can U give me any link for that so i can use it through Phonegap

Comment: @NaveenKumarMishra: lots of good tutorial available you can search. see basic tutorial for starting which [Phonegap](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap--mobile-2532)

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible you can design whole page in html and stored in Asset folder with image used,css,script folder,and in android activity you just open it in webView .

Comment: Can U give me some link where i can found this kind of demo

Answer (score 2):

go for step by step implemetation of phonegap using this tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap--mobile-2532

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use HTML instead of XML to create android UI.
[Check this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516865/ui-design-in-android-using-xml-or-html)